# Setup subdomain in new app directory with Cpanel cakephp

Tags: cakephp, hosting, subdomain, cpanel

I have working domain.kz with cakephp (Cpanel hosting)
www/app
www/cake
www/index.php

how can i setup admin.domain.kz to (app2)

www/app
www/app2
www/cake
www/index.php

Answer (score 1):

The way you want it - will be very difficult; you'll have to change several file/folder paths in several places. Instead, why don't you try to create an admin folder where you've the full cakephp application for admin.

So the resulting folder structure would be like this:

```
(domain.kz)
www/app
www/cake
www/index.php

(admin.domain.kz)
www/admin/app
www/admin/cake
www/admin/index.php
```

Then you'll have to point your subdomain (admin.domain.kz) to `/www/admin`.

Now assuming that you've configured your domain and subdomain correctly, if you try to browse your domain, it'll work with no issues but if you try to access your subdomain, it'll give you a 500 error. DON'T WORRY. It is expected.

The primary .htaccess file is forcing all requests served by primary webroot (www/app/webroot) folder. You'll have to change your primary .htaccess file (www/.htaccess) like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^admin\.domain\.kz$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Notice that, I've added two lines which tells that if you're trying to access your subdomain, stop rewriting; otherwise rewrite as usual. Cheers!!!

Comment: Didn't notice, it was asked 6 years ago. I was googling for the same problem and just solved it and stumbled into this question. :)

Comment: that's ok, the answer is not only for the one who asked originally, but for everyone who has the same problem and looks for a solution

Comment: this is awesome.

Answer (score 0):

If the cake apps are totally separate but share a cake library then the following might work:

You could use cPanel's 'Addon Domain' feature, once the DNS has been set up for admin.domain.kz. [Instructions can be found here](http://www.siteground.com/tutorials/cpanel/addon_domains.htm).

Set the document root of the addon domain to the www/app2 folder.

Then just make sure that CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH in www/app2/webroot/index.php points to ../../../cake